# Windows 11 note pad Is there any solution to stop it from reopening already open file?

Tags: windows, notepad

Is there any solution to stop it from reopening it if is already open ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1777262/if-i-try-to-open-a-txt-file-that-is-already-open-how-can-i-have-windows-go-to-t - read comments here, if you haven't already (because it seems like a duplicate account a bit).

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is a very basic text editor and was never meant to do
fancy things.

Notepad is not aware of the other instances of itself that are
currently running, and it does not keep a lock on the file it
currently processes.
This means that there no way to detect that a file is already open in
notepad.

If you require this functionality then you need to use a more evolved
text editor that is designed for this type of things, for example
[notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).